# Orlicz Norm and a result on expectation

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, convex-geometry

I am reading a [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.3629v1.pdf) which is mainly about Dobrushin's contraction coefficient and its generalization. In page 27, the following is defined:
Consider an arbitrary, non-negative, convex function $\psi:\mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ with $\psi(0)<1$. Then for an integrable random variable $X$ 
$$||X||_{\psi}:=\inf \{c>0:~\mathbb{E}[\psi(\frac{X}{c})]\leq 1\}.$$

Then letting $\psi^*$ be the convex conjugate of $\psi$, we can write the following for arbitrary random variables $X$ and $Y$ by Young's inequality: 
$$XY\leq \psi(X)+\psi^*(Y)$$ and hence, 
$$\mathbb{E}[XY]\leq 2||X||_{\psi}||Y||_{\psi^*}.$$

First of all, in the typical definition of Orlicz norm, it is assumed that $\psi(0)=0$ and also $\psi$ is non-decreasing. Why are those properties removed here?

Secondly, the last inequality is not clear to me. Can anybody proivde a hint on how to show that?

Comment: What do you know about $\frac{X}{\|X\|_{\phi}}\frac{Y}{\|Y\|_{\phi^*}}$ by Young's inequality and by the definition of the norm?

Comment: Please don't cross-post so soon together, (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/196356/orlicz-norm-and-a-result-on-expectation), or at least link to the previous question. Thanks.